# Why props variable can't be desctructed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a piece of JSX code, and I can't understand why one of the variants is not work. In my opinion the props variable must be destructed but it not happens.

There is code snippet on jsbin: https://jsbin.com/lijusef/4/edit?js,output

```
// It's works fine
const Hello = (props) => <h1>{props.message}</h1>

// But it generates an error
//const Hello = ({message}) => <h1>{message}</h1>

// Why I can't deconstruct the props variable?


ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello message="Hello" />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The error thrown on JSBin is:

> Parse Error: Line 2: Unexpected token => Error: Parse Error: Line 2: Unexpected token =>

I expect that lines

`const Hello = (props) => <h1>{props.message}</h1>`

and

`const Hello = ({message}) => <h1>{message}</h1>`

should be equivalent but it's not works this way. Why?

Comment: `// But it generates an error` what does the error say? That might be important.

Comment: JSBin is still using the deprecated JSXTransformer. Ideally, they'd switch to something more modern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use destructuring with props but as destructuring is ES6 feature, you will have to use Babel for the same.

Just change the dropdown in your JSBin from JSX(React) to ES6/Babel, it will work.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Huh, so although there's a `JSX (React)` option, the `ES6 / Babel` option *also* works perfectly (or even better) with JSX and React. Not something I would have expected, any idea what the point of the `JSX (React)` option might be? (also note that arrow functions are an ES6 feature as well, but they don't throw - seems like a JSXTransformer problem)